# BPF lib documentation

Tags: c, ebpf, bpf, libbpf

I have created an app with BPF library(https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf). Unfortunately it does not have documentation or at least I have not found it yet. Only thing I have found is this https://libbpf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html, but it does not have everything I need.

I would like to know, what is void *ctx for and what are these ring_buffer_opts in this function.

```
LIBBPF_API struct ring_buffer *
ring_buffer__new(int map_fd, ring_buffer_sample_fn sample_cb, void *ctx, const struct ring_buffer_opts *opts);
```

And here I would like to know what is void *ctx for.

```
typedef int (*ring_buffer_sample_fn)(void *ctx, void *data, size_t size);
```

I prefer link to the documentation, but I am glad for everything.

Comment: This appears to be a C library. Why did you use the C++ tag?

Comment: @Lundin I wanted more people to see it, because you can use C libraries in C++. But dont worry, the tag has been already removed.

Comment: That's not how this site works; tags should indicate what a question contains/is about. The C and C++ [tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) contain info for when to use C, C++ or both tags at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have found the GitHub mirror for the project (the “original” sources are in the Linux kernel repository) and the [official API documentation](https://libbpf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html). The latter is generated from the source code, in particular from the comments in `src/libbpf.h`. It may be that the documentation is not entirely up-to-date, it seems that the description for a few functions is currently missing in the HTML-rendered documentation.

However, not all functions have been documented yet, and the ring buffer API does not have much on this side to help you. So the best I can suggest is to look at the code and at existing examples. There are at least two selftests in the kernel repository which are using `ring_buffer__new()`: [`ringbuf.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/prog_tests/ringbuf.c#L152) and [`ringbuf_multi.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/prog_tests/ringbuf_multi.c#L83).

The first one (`ringbuf.c`) calls it like this:

```c
    ringbuf = ring_buffer__new(skel->maps.ringbuf.map_fd,
                   process_sample, NULL, NULL);
```

It passes a pointer to a function called `process_sample` as the second argument, `NULL` as `ctx` for the third argument, and `NULL` as well for the options.

The callback function, `process_sample`, is called by `ring_buffer__poll()` or `ring_buffer__consume()` [on each sample to “process” them](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/tools/lib/bpf/ringbuf.c#L231) according to user's needs. In this example, the callback only works on the `data` from the sample, printing a line which content depends on whether this is the first or second sample retrieved. The callback needs no “context”: this is why the `ctx` argument, which is stored by `ring_buffer__new()` and then passed to the callback function as its first argument each time it runs, is `NULL` in this case.

For the second example (`ringbuf_multi.c`), we get a `ctx`:

```c
    ringbuf = ring_buffer__new(bpf_map__fd(skel->maps.ringbuf1),
                   process_sample, (void *)(long)1, NULL);
    [...]
    
    err = ring_buffer__add(ringbuf, bpf_map__fd(skel->maps.ringbuf2),
                  process_sample, (void *)(long)2);
```

The callback function is named `process_sample` again, but it's a different one (it's defined in the same file as the rest of the example). We also pass a context, `1`, and then we add an *additional ring buffer*, with a *different* context, `2`. If you look at the checks that are performed under that, and at how `process_sample` is defined, it should give you a good overview of how the `ctx` works: it is some generic context that you can pass to each individual ring buffer, so that you can process your samples in a different way based on which ring buffer it falls into.

As for the `struct ring_buffer_opts *` options, always at `NULL` in the examples, they seem to be [unused for now](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.h#L890). [The code in `ring_buffer__new()` does not use them](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/tools/lib/bpf/ringbuf.c#L161).

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I did not know, I can use 2 maps to 1 ring buffer. But if I would rather create 2 function instead of using 2 contexts. I think, It is for some different data.